# How to initialize Parse and point to serverURL using Angular2

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, angular

I am attempting to use a Parse server and am currently running into issues with initializing Parse in javascript and pointing to the correct serverURL. Curious if anyone else has had any luck doing this with Angular2 yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Parse server within an Angular 1 application, but the code works for both. I'm initializing Parse in a own Parse service, which provides some handy helper methods. But I think it doesn't matter where you run this code.

```
var appId = 'appId';
var jsKey = 'jsKey'; // I think this is not used anymore
Parse.initialize(appId, jsKey);
Parse.serverURL = 'yourNewServerUrl.com';
```

Comment: I have my own parse.service.ts file. But when I try Parse.serverURL = environment.ParseServerUrl; I receive such err - Cannot assign to 'serverURL' because it is a constant or a read-only property. Any thoughts? Thx

Comment: @VitaliiTrachenko `(Parse as any).serverURL = 'parse_url';` try this.

Answer (score 8):

For frameworks that use typescript (ex. angular 2, ionic 2 & 3),

To solve the typescript read-only error:

> Typescript Error
>
> Cannot assign to 'serverURL' because it is a constant or a read-only
> property.
>
> ```
> Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse';
> ```

Use `(Parse as any)` instead of `Parse` to set the value of *serverUrl* such as:

```
import * as Parse from 'parse';

Parse.initialize('appId', 'jsKey');  // use your appID & your js key
(Parse as any).serverURL = 'http://localhost:1337/parse'; // use your server url
```

This require parse and @types/parse to be installed:

```
npm install --save @types/parse parse
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but I've found the trick when the typescript throws a `Cannot assign to 'serverURL' because it is a constant or a read-only property`

```
// Use parse with typescript
import * as Parse from 'parse';
// To set the server URL
let parse = require('parse');
```

Now you have access to `parse.serverUrl`, which is the same as `Parse.serverUrl` except that the TS definition will throw a read-only error.

Comment: When I use `require('parse')`, tons of errors appear upon compiling.

Comment: now you have to use const instead of let. This solved my issue.