# How to use Parse SDK with Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, parse-platform, angular-services, parse-server

I'm trying to do a GET request on a Parse backend but i have a 403 response from the server.
I tried to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868599/how-to-initialize-parse-and-point-to-serverurl-using-angular2/51350996#51350996) but i still have the issue.

Here's the configuration of my service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import * as Parse from 'parse';


Parse.initialize('MY APP ID', 'MY MASTER KEY ID'); // use your appID & your js key
(Parse as any).serverURL = 'https://MYURL/parse'; // use your server url


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BackofficeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getStores(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(Parse.serverURL + '/classes/Stores');
  }
```

I tried to add an empty paramater for the jskey (because i used master key instead of JS key) but it didn't work.

```
Parse.initialize('MY APP ID', '', 'MY MASTER KEY ID'); // use your appID & your js key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the Rest API of the Parse server, but you configure it with the SDK.

As you configure the SDK and you have it, I really recommend you to use it.
Here is how to get all object of stores.

```
var Stores = Parse.Object.extend("Stores");
var query = new Parse.Query(Stores);
query.find().then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: It helps a lot ! I did succeed to get all object of stores with the code you gave me.
I'm new with Parse server so i need to work on it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad that it helps you if you have any other question just let me know

Comment: It was not what i had in mind so i think i will try to figure out how to do what i want differently.

Comment: Ok no problem, just let me know

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by using what [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7618742/julien-kode) gave me and modifying my service into a promise :

```
  public getStores(): Promise <any> {
  const Stores = Parse.Object.extend('Stores');
  const query = new Parse.Query(Stores);
  return query.find()
}
```